# How to get cell value if I know column name in gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, datatable

I have 'GridView1' and 'label1' like this:

```
ID___________NAME___________SELECT

1 --------- NAME1 --------- button

2 --------- NAME2 --------- button

3 --------- NAME3 --------- button

4 --------- NAME4 --------- button

lable1 = null
```

If I hit any button in SELECT column, I want display the ID of the people I selected to the label1, for example if I hit button of the first row, it should display:

```
label1: You have selected people with ID = 1
```

how can I do that?

Comment: with postback or without postback?

Comment: @RameezAhmedSayad: Say with post back.

Comment: @RonaldinhoState can you tell us how you handle button click event??

Comment: there are different ways of doing it... you can try one. try google it first

Comment: @AmitSingh: If I know how to handle it then shouldn't I ask this queston LOL, j/k what do you mean?

Comment: i wana know how you handle the button click event i mean on which evet row_command or select commad or anything else

Comment: @AmitSingh I dont know, whatever works I will follow.

Comment: if your are ready to folow whatever work than i think @Damith answer is suitable and appropriate for u

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use the following source code

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="btnConfirm" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' OnClick="btnConfirm_Click"  />
```

and this cs code

---

```
protected void btnHClear_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = GridView1.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(((ImageButton)sender).CommandArgument.ToString())].Cells[1].Text;
}
```

---

Comment: should be [0] because I need ID column, and it is just Button not ImageButton. Thank you ALL of you! :))

Answer (score 3):

In gridview `SelectedIndexChanged` event you can get id as below

```
var id = GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Values[0];
```

but you need to set `DataKeyNames="ID"` in your grid view markup in the aspx page

by using id value now you can set the label text.

```
Label1.Text = "You have selected people with ID = " +id;
```

Answer (score 3):

Taking your GridView as you have shown , means exactly 3 Columns only.

For the SELECT column having buttons, Set the `CommandName` property of buttons to Select.

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Button ID="selectBTN" runat="server" CommandName="Select" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Set the OnSelectedIndexChanged event for GridView.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" DataKeyNames="CustomerID"  runat="server"     
      OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_Selected" >
```

Now in the event handler set the Label value as:

```
 protected void GridView1_Selected(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            GridViewRow row = GridView1.SelectedRow; // Get the selected row 
           // Get the Column value, Cells[0] represents first column: ID ,
           //Cells[1] represents second column : NAME, etc...
            labelName.Text = row.Cells[0].Text;   

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at below link:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/thread/153329/changing-gridview-row-color-on-row-command.aspx

IN which you have to change in this part

```
if (e.CommandName == "Select")
    {            
        int rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        GridViewRow row = gviewRetailers.Rows[index];
        Label1.Text =  "You have selected people with ID = " + row.Cells[0].Text;
    }
```

Thanks,
Hitesh